# cmake - When to include include_directories in a CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, curl, makefile, cmake

I have a C++ project in which I have the following line:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

I am using the `CURL` library to access IMU data from a sensor. I prepared a `CMakeLists.txt` file that looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(imu_data_access_cmake_test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(SOURCES imu_data_access.cpp ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}/curl/curl.h)
add_executable(imu_data_access_cmake_test ${SOURCES})
#add_executable(imu_data_access_cmake_test imu_data_access.cpp)
target_link_libraries(imu_data_access_cmake_test ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

This works very well. However, if I remove the `include_directories` line and modify the `add_executable` line to just use my `imu_data_access.cpp` as source, the `cmake` does not throw an error and everything still works. I am assuming this is due to `target_link_libraries` line.

How to know whether a library should be included using `include_directories` or `target_link_libraries`? If the package/library has a `.so` file can we simply ignore `include_directories` for that package/library?

**Edit: How to know whether a library should be included using `include_directories` vs. `target_link_libraries`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to know whether a library should be included using `include_directories` or `target_link_libraries`?

Unless a library is a header-only library, call to `target_link_libraries` is required for use it.

If `Find*` script (called by `find_package()` call) sets variable with include directories (this information can be obtained from the script's documentation), it assumes that these directories will be included (via `include_directories` or `target_include_directories`).

Propagating include directories through the `target_link_libraries` occurred in case of *IMPORTED* target, usually named as `<namespace>::<name>`.

---

In your specific case `include_directories` have no effect only because given directory is searched by a compiler *by default*, this is usual when library is installed through package manager. But `find_package` is intended to work even with non-system installations.

Comment: So, if a directory is present in system's path, it will be picked up by compiler even if I don't use `include_directories`?

Comment: Also, my question was intended to be **How to know whether a library should be included using `include_directories` vs `target_link_libraries`?**

Comment: Yes, compiler has notion about system paths, so it includes these directories in any case. As for your question, "vs" is wrong - `target_link_libraries` should be used **in any case**. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A good practice is to use `target_include_directories()` instead of `include_directories()`. The benefit is that you can indicate the visibility of the include, for example if you configure a library with:

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC foo_include)
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE private_include)
```

Then, if you link `foo` to an executable `bar`, then `bar` will have access to the `foo_include` directory, but not to `private_include`. Command `include_directories()` apply to the directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` contains the command, so it will apply to any library/executable declared in this directory and its sub-directories.

For `target_link_libraries()`, then the behavior varies, because it can be a list of libraries, in which case there is no notion of include directories. But it can be an [IMPORTED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) library, where it can contain more information, such as include directories (for example, Boost and Qt do that).

In the case of cURL, the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html) indicates that `CURL_LIBRARIES` contains the list of libraries. In your case, the cURL headers are probably found because by default CMake will search for headers in standard locations, so `target_link_libraries()` has no impact regarding the includes in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things that may help you improve your code.

### Avoid overspecifying minimum version

I generally like to make sure that my CMake scripts don't overspecify the version.  It seems to me that in this script, anything more than version 3.1 would work. So I'd be inclined to change that first line to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
```

### Handle packages consistently

As you know, `find_package()` generally sets the `package_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `package_LIBRARIES` for the package.  I find that consistently using such variables is much better for simplifying maintenance of the CMake script than trimming to the bare minimum.  Therefore I'd not worry about whether they're required or not and do this:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(imu_data_access_cmake_test imu_data_access.cpp)
target_link_libraries(imu_data_access_cmake_test ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

### Don't put system includes in sources

Note that I have omitted this line:

```
set(SOURCES imu_data_access.cpp ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS}/curl/curl.h)
```

Not every library include file needs to be or should be listed as a source.  As a general rule, I only include *my* sources, and that's what I'd advice for your projects as well.

Comment: If I strip the CMake script to minimum, will it reduce the compilation time? Are there any disadvantages for not avoiding unnecessarily including files/ lines in CMake?

Comment: Since the include file is needed during compilation anyway, omitting the `include_directories` line from the CMake is unlikely to make any measurable difference in compilation time.  Time it on your machine to verify.